# Issue with Date conversion in SQL script

Tags: sql-server, date

I am using SQL to convert a column `[INT_DATE_CREATED]` for conversion and in this column date is look like nvarchar: `22-OCT-15 01.52.57.192000000 PM`

I am trying to convert column `[INT_DATE_CREATED]` into date as below

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE, [INT_DATE_CREATED], 104) AS [INT_DATE_CREATED] 
FROM tablexyz
```

No success and facing below error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any quick help for conversion would be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The closest format is 106. So, try this:

```
select convert(date, left(replace(int_date_created, '-', ' '), 9), 106)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
select convert (date,left(int_date_created, 9),104)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Sample will help you to get preferred output.

**SAMPLE:**

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(100) = '22-OCT-15 01.52.57.192000000 PM'
SELECT CONVERT (DATE,LEFT(@date,9))
```

**Note:** Modify conversion with your own style.